# Adding data to the database and how to make it right

Tags: c#, sql, optimization

I have been writing some simple c# and I usually use the same class and functions that insert and grab the data from the database.

For example, this is my function:

```
    public bool insert_and_ConfirmSQL(String Query, String comments)
    {
        bool success = false;
        NpgsqlCommand cmd = new NpgsqlCommand();
        NpgsqlConnection mycon = new NpgsqlConnection();
        string connstring = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1}; User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};timeout=1000;CommandTimeout=120;", tbHost, tbPort, tbUser, tbPass, tbDataBaseName);
        mycon.ConnectionString = connstring;
        cmd = mycon.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = Query;
        mycon.Open();

        int temp = 0;
        try
        {
            temp = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            success = true;
        }
        catch
        {
           if (mycon.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                mycon.Close();
            }
        }

        return success;
    }
```

Now I know that this query is not safe against injections and I need to use prepared statements. But I don't understand how should I approach this when each of my queries is different? is there a "universal" function that inserts any query and "prepares" it?

Comment: I assume you are trying to prevent SQL injection attacks. Can you show how your Query string is being constructed, because that's what actually counts here. In your code sample, you're just passing in the SQL query as a parameter - we have no way to see how that query is being put together; that's where your injection-prevention efforts should be focused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a more generalized way of performing inserts/updates/deletes, perhaps the following is suitable (uses SqlClient but is easily adapted for NpgsqlClient):

```
public static object ExecuteActionProcedure(System.Data.CommandType CommandType, string CommandText, string[] Parameters, object[] Values)
{
  try
  {
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
    {
      con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnection"].ConnectionString;
      con.Open();
      using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
      {

        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType;
        cmd.CommandText = CommandText;
        SqlParameter result = new SqlParameter();
        result.ParameterName = "ResultValue";
        result.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
        cmd.Parameters.Add(result);
        for (int i = 0; i < Parameters.Length; i++)
        {
          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(Parameters[i], Values[i]);
        }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        return (int)result.Value;
      }
    }
  }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    return null;
  }
}
```

Call statement:

```
ExecuteActionProcedure(CommandType.StoredProcedure, "aspnet_SaveFullName", new string[] { "UserName", "FullName" }, new object[] { model.UserName, model.FullName });
```

Note that you can pass this method an SQL string that includes parameters as well as a stored procedure.

Answer (score 3):

I would advise you to use it this way because the using statement takes care of diposing connection & command

Also in order to take safety against sqlinjection please SqlParameters (equivalent in Npgsl) to pass value

public void insert_and_ConfirmSQL(String Query, String comments)
{

```
     using(NpgsqlConnection mycon = new NpgsqlConnection())
      {
        using(NpgsqlCommand cmd = mycon.CreateCommand())
        {
              string connstring = String.Format("Server={0};Port={1}; User Id={2};Password={3};Database={4};timeout=1000;CommandTimeout=120;", tbHost, tbPort, tbUser, tbPass, tbDataBaseName);
              mycon.ConnectionString = connstring;
              cmd = mycon.CreateCommand();
             cmd.CommandText = Query;
              mycon.Open();

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       }
     }
```

}

Comment: Although he should be employing the `using` command to close connections and clean up resources, his question seems to actually be about avoiding SQL injection attacks. Perhaps your answer should go into the comments section instead?

Comment: I don't see how this prevents sql injection

Comment: @Greg in my answer i have advised OP to use SqlParameters (equivalent in Npgsl) to pass value